# Sharing text message to Instagram Direct

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, sharing

I want to find way sharing text message to Instagram Direct. I already find [URL scheme](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) in Instagram dev doc, but there is no one word about sharing to direct. I also check some third part libraries - nothing helpful. If sharing to Direct is impossible with using URL scheme, maybe you know another way for this. Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for this elsewhere by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible but other alternatives you could try is to screen shot you text messages or copying and pasting your messages in Instagram direct and sending them.
I hope this has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**A Bit Late To Answer (Aug 2022)**

This is a similar topic that I answered earlier, I was successfully able to achieve the solution, please refer to my solution on the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73213888/4360419

Precisely, there is a deep link available to solve this,

```
instagram://sharesheet?text={anyThingYouWantToShare}
```