# Instagram - share image, text and url via iOS app : swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I am trying to share image with some text and a url from my app to Instagram which would later redirect to iOS app installed on the phone from Instagram app. I am able to share image on instagram but not with text and url. Any help related to the same would be great!

Comment: check on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios/28272642#28272642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram had removed pushing custom captions to their app while sharing photos at one point, [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915122/instagram-instagramcaption-not-working/31917013#31917013).

I also understand, according to the [Instagram iPhone Hooks](https://help.instagram.com/355896521173347) page, that you can pass a photo only to the "Select A Filter" Instagram screen, which is before you set a caption. I'm sorry, but I don't think Instagram supports custom captions.

Answer (score 8):

**A Bit Late To Answer (Aug, 2022)**

I have successfully cracked the plain text sharing on Instagram by myself, after doing a lot of research on google on this topic. You can use the mentioned deep link to open Instagram Direct with some text to share from your application,

```
instagram://sharesheet?text={AnyTextOrLinkToShare}
```

Moreover, the below code should work on iOS to launch Instagram Direct (Messenger) from your app with some content

```
if let url = URL(string: "instagram://sharesheet?text=https://google.com/") {
   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Not sure, why did they hide this information from their official documentation but now who cares, I have achieved it with the continuous efforts of 16-18 hrs! :)

Comment: unbelievable that they left this out of the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is not official way to share image/sticker together with a text/link to Instagram - because **"com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL"** parameter bacame unavailable or private.

But there is one workaround how to proceed working with image/sticker & text/url consequentially described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74241318/20343737

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33056221)